# Decode email body in php gmail api?

Tags: php, gmail-api

I'm trying to read the email body usign Gmail API

*I was using IMAP but for performance reasons(reading emails takes so much time in IMAP) I have to move to Gmail API which is considerably faster.*

The issue is where I'm trying to decode the Body, with IMAP is simple, just read the transfer encodings from imap_fetchstructure return and use the appropriate function to decode. (imap_qprint,imap_7bit, etc)

And for Gmail

```
        $message = $service->users_messages->get($user, $msg->id, ["format"=>"full"]);

        $payload = $message->getPayload();
        $mime = $payload->getMimeType();
        $body = $payload->getBody();
        $headers = $payload->getHeaders();
        $content = $body->getData();
        $decoded = base64_decode($content);
```

The variable $contents is the body in base64 but If I decode includes strange characters like ��ѽ��� that didn't happened with IMAP. 
The content is plain text UTF-8 no additional parts or attachment, just plain text. And it happens with HTML as well.

These are the relevants headers

```
     [{"name":"MIME-Version","value":"1.0"},
{"name":"Content-Type","value":"text\/plain; charset=utf-8"},
{"name":"Content-Transfer-Encoding","value":"quoted-printable"}]
```

I think the issue is that the body is quoted-printable but even if I use imap_qprint or quoted_printable_decode over the decoded base64 these strange characters continue.

Comment: Hi, is quoted-printable

Comment: decode the body content using imap_qprint or quoted_printable_decode

Comment: seems to be related to this http://php.net/manual/en/function.imap-base64.php#102766

Comment: The issue was that the variable $content is not base64, is base64url, 
https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/get?hl=es-419
Fixed with this:
http://php.net/manual/es/function.base64-decode.php#118244
And then using imap_qprint

Answer (score 10):

I was having the same problem...Felipe Morales got at the solution...but to be a bit more explicit:

Take the base64-url-encoded string from the API response, and run it through this function:

```
function gmailBodyDecode($data) {
    $data = base64_decode(str_replace(array('-', '_'), array('+', '/'), $data)); 
    //from php.net/manual/es/function.base64-decode.php#118244

    $data = imap_qprint($data);
    return($data);
}
```

Works like a champ...

Comment: Works great! One comment, the "impa_qprint" function can be replaced by the php baseline function "quoted_printable_decode".